# Poster in tikzposter not compiling

Tags: math-mode, tikzposter

I am right now in the process of writing a poster in tikzposter but am having problems with LaTex. At times it ignores the errors (I do not understand how they arise) and compiles but by now it just declines to compile.

The common error displayed is that boxes in which I use (nested) Maths environments he does not accept the closing "}".

Thank you very much for your time.

```
\documentclass[24pt, a0paper, landscape]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{columns}

\column{.33}

\block{Measure Theory}{
    \begin{definition}
        (p.15 3.1, Schilling). A $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$ on a set X is a family of subsets of X with the following properties:
        \begin{tabbing}
            \=Nationality: \=Mathematician \= dissambeletheroadissupposedtobeverylong \= this \kill
            \> ($\Sigma_{1}$) \> $X \in \mathscr{A}$, \\
            \> ($\Sigma_{2}$) \> $A \in \mathscr{A} \Rightarrow A^{c} \in \mathscr{A}$, \\
            \> ($\Sigma_{3}$) \> $ \left( A_{j} \right)_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathscr{A} \Rightarrow \bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} A_{j} \in \mathscr{A}$. \\
        \end{tabbing}
        A set $A \in \mathscr{A}$ is said to be ($\mathscr{A}$) - measurable. 
    \end{definition}
    \begin{definition}
        (p.78, Schilling). $\int u \cdot d\lambda^{n}$ is called the n-dimensional Lebesgue integral and for $u \in \mathscr{L}^{1}_{\bar{\mathbb{R}}} (\lambda^{n})$, we say that u is Lebesgue integrable.
    \end{definition}
}

\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Dear Ebo, the error I am getting is "Something's wrong - perhaps a missing \item. }". It furthermore marks the line where the block is supposed to be closed red.

Comment: It seems your problem is occurred by the fact you use a `\newtheorem`-defined environment nested within a `\block`... but I don't know why, sorry!

Comment: Do you think I could circumvent the problem by using     \textbf{Definition} and then manually adjust the formatting?

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. I got it to work manually which should suffice in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to manually replace the more elegant definition of theorems in the front with the manual environment within the file itself and hence avoid the "newtheorem" command. It is not the most elegant solution but it suffices for a poster.

```
\documentclass[24pt, a0paper, landscape]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{columns}

\column{.33}

\block{Measure Theory}{
\textbf{Definition}
\textit{
    (p.15 3.1, Schilling). A $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$ on a set X is a family of subsets of X with the following properties:
    \begin{tabbing}
        \=Nationality: \=Mathematician \= dissambeletheroadissupposedtobeverylong \= this \kill
        \> ($\Sigma_{1}$) \> $X \in \mathscr{A}$, \\
        \> ($\Sigma_{2}$) \> $A \in \mathscr{A} \Rightarrow A^{c} \in \mathscr{A}$, \\
        \> ($\Sigma_{3}$) \> $ \left( A_{j} \right)_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathscr{A} \Rightarrow \bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} A_{j} \in \mathscr{A}$. \\
    \end{tabbing}
    A set $A \in \mathscr{A}$ is said to be ($\mathscr{A}$) - measurable.}
\textbf{Definition}
\textit{
    (p.78, Schilling). $\int u \cdot d\lambda^{n}$ is called the n-dimensional Lebesgue integral and for $u \in \mathscr{L}^{1}_{\bar{\mathbb{R}}} (\lambda^{n})$, we say that u is Lebesgue integrable.}
}

\end{columns}

\end{document}
```